# How to replace or remove the spl character in xml

Tags: c#

Am creating an xml file using xmlwriter,i thought it works fine but when i try to validate it fails bcoz there is spl character (BOM) appears like below,just gone thru forum seen lot of people adive me to use "SecurityElement.Escape". Am not sure how and where.Some one please guide me to remove this spl charecter from the xml file.

```
Ã¯Â»Â¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

if found the code for the above symbol

It look like `&#195;&#175;&#194;&#187;&#194;&#191;&#060;`

My Code

```
             XmlWriter xmlWrite;
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                xmlWrite = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\test.xml",settings);
            xmlWrite.WriteStartElement("metadata");
            xmlWrite.WriteElementString("story", story);
            xmlWrite.Close();
```

i can succesfully remove the version but still the spl characters are there . Am stuck now.

Any help  ?

This is the Answer to help me to get rid of the spl char

```
                    XmlWriter xmlWrite;
                    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);//Thanks to DaveE
                    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
                    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                    xmlWrite = XmlWriter.Create(@"c:\test.xml",settings);
```

when am append i used "using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\test.xml")) to work it out

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
           doc.Load(@"C:\test.xml");
            XmlNode newChild = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "image", null);
            var attribute = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
            attribute.Value = nameOnly;
            newChild.Attributes.Append(attribute);
            XmlNode xmlElement = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "width", null);
            xmlElement.InnerText = widthValue[1].TrimStart();
            newChild.AppendChild(xmlElement);
            using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml")) 
            {
                doc.Save(sw);

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you "try to validate it", what do you mean? XML validators shouldn't have any trouble with a BOM. And escaping the BOM is going to produce invalid XML.

If you want to us XMLWriterSettings, you need to create it, set the values you want, then use it when you create the XMLWriter. XMLWriter.Settings *is* read-only.

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

writer = XmlWriter.Create("c:\test.xml", settings);
```

That doesn't look like a normal BOM there, btw. Some of the bytes are correct, but there's junk in it. What code page is set on your system?

**EDIT**: Add Encoding to your XMLWriterSettings object:

`settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);`

The 'false' parameter tells the Encoding not to use a BOM.

Comment: ,thanks for your comment, i used "http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0" this to validate my xml and found the spl char in front of the version,so i tried omit settings to remove the version but still the spl char is front of my root node now.

Comment: That tool will validate *plain xmt text* but not xml *file contents* if the file contains a BOM.

Comment: What are you using to open the file? It should be a plain text editor like Notepad or Notepad++, not a word processor.

Comment: you saved my life.Shoot this piece of code done the magic "ettings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);"

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, even if it wasn't readonly you'd get a null reference exception because you don't initialize `xmlWrite` until line 5.

1. Create the writer (hint: line 5)
2. Set the settings, which you don't need to create. (hint: lines 3 and 4)
3. ???
4. Profit.

Comment: i jsut updated my question.I can remove the version now but still the spl char is there.